# Match one column with another and create new ones with matched input

Tags: r, join, merge

I have two data sets with some country codes,
The first one looks something like this and is written in CountryCode1

| Country1(code1) | Country2(code1) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |

And the second one something like this, with the information about the codes: CountryCode1 and CountryCode2

| CountryCode1 | CountryCode2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 51 |
| 2 | 52 |
| 3 | 53 |
| 4 | 54 |

I want to match or translate the CountryCodes1 of the first table with the CountryCodes2 of the second table, but keeping all 4 columns. I thought I could use `mutate()` to create two new columns, but I am not sure what else to use. Merging is not an option because I could not keep my original two columns that way. Maybe with mutate and a join?

| Country1 | Country2 | Country1(code2) | Country2(code2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 51 | 52 |
| 1 | 3 | 51 | 53 |
| 1 | 4 | 51 | 54 |

Edit: I cannot use the package `Countrycode`

Comment: Can you share a sample data  for a better output ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do two left joins, here with `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

data1 |> 
  left_join(data2,
            by = c("Country1(code1)" = "CountryCode1")) |>
  left_join(data2,
            by = c("Country2(code1)" = "CountryCode1"))
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  `Country1(code1)` `Country2(code1)` CountryCode2.x CountryCode2.y
              <dbl>             <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1                 1                 2             51             52
2                 1                 3             51             53
3                 1                 4             51             54
```

Data:

```r
library(readr)

data1 <- read_table("Country1(code1)    Country2(code1)
1   2
1   3
1   4")

data2 <- read_table("CountryCode1   CountryCode2
1   51
2   52
3   53
4   54")
```

(You might want to work a bit on your column-naming to make et easier for yourself).